# Cambiar el formato a una fecha dentro de un texto en Linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Tengo el siguiente archivo:

```
/Contadores/Shells/6_BSCS_IN_FROM_EMM|SH_1.sh|rC|16/10/2020|TI46
/Contadores/Shells/6_BSCS_IN_FROM_EMM|SH_1.sh|rC|16/10/2020|TI44
/Contadores/Shells/6_BSCS_IN_FROM_EMM|SH_1.sh|rC|16/10/2020|TI45
```

Lo que deseo que me quede como resultado es lo siguiente:

```
/Contadores/Shells/6_BSCS_IN_FROM_EMM|SH_1.sh|rC|2020-10-16|TI46;TI44;TI45
```

Siendo el primer cambio:

1. La fecha cambio de 16/10/2020 a este formato 2020-10-16, es decir las fechas en el archivo deben tener el formato yyyy-mm-dd
2. Se agrupo los campos y la columna no repetida se puso entre ;
3. Siendo la última columna siempre distinta y se le debe separar con punto y coma.

**Intente hacerlo con esta sentencia:**

```
echo "23/11/2020" | awk -F/ '{printf "%s-%s-%s\n",$3,$2,$1}' 
resultado: 2020-11-23
```

Pero solo me corrige cuando existe un solo campo, pero mi ejemplo tiene mas campos en el archivo.

Agradeceré su ayuda

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes! Pregunta: has probado algo? Puedes editar la pregunta y contarnos qué has probado para resolver tu pregunta (el código) junto con los errores que te hayas cruzado.

Comment: coincido con @Alfabravo. Además, ¿cuál es la lógica? ¿Solo vale en este caso concreto o hay que generalizar? Es decir, ¿siempre es el último campo el diferente? ¿Siempre hay que sumar 4 días? Todo eso deberías añadirlo a la pregunta vía [edit].

Comment: Intente hacerlo con esta sentencia:

echo "23/11/2020" | awk -F/ '{printf "%s-%s-%s\n",$3,$2,$1}' 
resultado: 2020-11-23